# How to select between a list css classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a **div** with a **next** and **previous** button

```
<div class="b1"></div>
<input type="button" class="btnP" value="Prev"/>
<input type="button" class="btnN" value="Next"/>
```

and a list of css classes

```
.b1 { background-color:#fff;}
.b2 { background-color:#000;}
.b3 { background-color:#123;}
.b4 { background-color:#444;}
.b5 { background-color:#bbb;}
```

which i want to use for that **div** when the user press the **next** or **previous** button by that numbering order.

> This is what i did so far:
>   http://jsfiddle.net/51dq5num/

```
var size_ini = 1;
$(".btnN").click(function () { 
    var size_increase = size_ini++;
    var size_increase1 = size_ini;
    $("#content").html("<span>" + size_increase + "</span>").removeClass().addClass("b" + size_increase);
    if (size_increase > 4) {
        size_ini = 1;
    }
});
```

I manage to get the **next button** working but i'm not sure how to do it for the **previous button**

Is there a better way to do this rather then adding and removing css classes from the **div**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var newClass = function(div, next) {
    div[0].className = div[0].className.replace(/b\d+/, "b" + newClass[next ? 'next' : 'prev']());
};
newClass.atual = 1;
newClass.last = 5;
newClass.next = function(){
    this.atual = (this.atual == this.last ? 1 : this.atual + 1);
    return this.atual;
};
newClass.prev = function(){
    this.atual = (this.atual == 1 ? this.last : this.atual - 1);
    return this.atual;
};


var myDiv = $("#content");
$(".btnN").click(function () { 
    newClass(myDiv, true);
});
$(".btnP").click(function () { 
    newClass(myDiv, false);
});
```

[Jsfiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/51dq5num/6/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
$(".btnP").click(function () {
        var size_increase = $("#content").attr("class").substring(2, 1);
        size_increase--;
        if (size_increase < 1) {
            size_increase = 5;
        }
        $("#content").html("<span>" + size_increase + "</span>").removeClass().addClass("b" + size_increase);       
    });
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/51dq5num/7/

Answer (score 1):

This is a combined solution for both buttons.

```
var size_ini = 0;
$("input[type='button']").click(function () { 
    if($(this).hasClass("btnN"))
    {
        size_ini=size_ini+1;
        var c="b"+size_ini;
        $("#content").removeClass().addClass(c).html("TG"+size_ini);
    }
    else
    {
         size_ini=size_ini-1;
         var c="b"+size_ini;
         $("#content").removeClass().addClass(c).html("TG"+size_ini);
    }
});
```

Note as it is not mentioned i have not checked on the max condition thus `btnP` can increase the counter infinitely.You can put it in a condn and limit it to a max value.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/n8dLgh3L/1/

Here is js code to increase and decrease.

```
var size_ini = 0;
$(".btnN").click(function () {
    if (size_ini > 4) {
        size_ini = 1;
    } else {
        size_ini++
    }
    $("#content").html("<span>" + size_ini + "</span>").removeClass().addClass("b" + size_ini);

});

$(".btnP").click(function () {
    var size_decrease = $("#content").attr("class").substring(1, 2);

    if (size_decrease <= 1) {
        size_decrease = 5;
    } else {
        size_decrease--;
    }
    $("#content").html("<span>" + size_decrease + "</span>").removeClass().addClass("b" + size_decrease);       
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You ca achieve this with the help of .substr() for incrementing the number of class. Have a look.

```
    function Getnumber(classNumber,nav)
    {
        var no=0;
        if(nav=="P")
        {
            no=parseInt(classNumber.substr(1,2))-1;
        }
        else
        {
            no=parseInt(classNumber.substr(1,2))+1;
        }
        return no;
    }

    $(".btnN").on("click",function(){
      var oldClass=$('div').attr("class");
      var num=Getnumber(oldClass,"N");
      if(num<6)
        $('div').addClass("b"+num).removeClass(oldClass);
    });
   $(".btnP").on("click",function(){
      var oldClass=$('div').attr("class");
      var num=Getnumber(oldClass,"P");
      if(num>0)
        $('div').addClass("b"+num).removeClass(oldClass);
   });
```

Feel free to ask.